# Uno-Platform: Cross Platform Library, #if conditional for Wasm?

Tags: uno-platform

In pre 4.0 Uno-Platform, I was able to use the `#if __WASM__` compiler directive for WebAssembly specific code in a cross platform class library.  This was very useful for creating Wasm-specific widgets using the Wasm specific `SetHtmlAttribute` method.

However, in version 4.0 Uno-Platform, my code isn't building because the compiler isn't finding the `__WASM__` constant.  I hesitate adding it manually to the libraries *.csproj file ...

```xml
<DefineConstants Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netstandard'))">__WASM__;$(DefineConstants);</DefineConstants>
```

... because I'm afraid it will build if the target is WPF.  So, is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your approach covers the scenario where a given API is available on all Uno targets, it will not work in case it really is Wasm or Skia specific, unfortunately. For those cases though we have another type of library - **cross-runtime library** (see [docs](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started-dotnet-new.html?q=templa#uno-platform-blank-cross-runtime-library)). Currently this kind of library can only be created via `dotnet` command-line tooling:

```
dotnet new unolib-crossruntime -o MyCrossRuntimeLibrary
```

By default it generates the following solution layout:

[image: Solution layout for cross-runtime library]

Both projects are pointing to the same source-code files, however the ".Wasm" one is specifically referencing the WebAssembly runtime and will correctly adhere to `#if __WASM__` declarations. Similarly you could create another project for ".Skia" to have Skia-specific declarations.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was seeking!  Thanks, Martin.

Comment: this one should be marked as the accepted answer I believe :)

Answer (score 2):

Doh!  I don't know why I had not noticed this before!  Looks like `SetHtmlAttribute` is implemented on all Uno target platforms!  So, rather than using the `#if __WASM__` compiler directive, I can use `#if !WINDOWS_UWP` and implemented my Wasm code knowing it will be ignored on the other Uno target platforms.

Very clever, Uno Team!